# Conditional filtering based on user inputs in Shiny

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, leaflet

User new to Shiny here. I am trying to create an interactive map which adds circle markers based on 2 groups of users inputs: where each group has 3 possible inputs. I can't seem to figure out how to write the code to properly filter the data and then add the filtered data as circle markers. The filtering logic should go like this:

1) If Religion / Denomination / World = "All", skip that specific filter. (e.g. If Religion 1 = "All", do not filter by Religion 1, but still filter by the rest of the fields if they are not "All").

2) If denomination 1 / 2 is "None", only return the information of the Religion, and exclude the denomination info. (E.g. If Religion 1 = "Christians", Denomination = "None", Geography = "United Kingdom", only the Christian Totals in the UK should be mapped).

3) For all other specific inputs, apply the & operator. (E.g. If Religion 1 = "Christians", Denomination = "Catholics", Geography = "United Kingdom", it should only show Catholics in the UK).

I guess I could just write multiple if / else statements for each possible permutation, but then there will be a lot of conditions and I will have to repeat them twice so that it works for group 1 and group 2.

The year slider input filter should be reactive while the rest of the selectInputs should only work after the user clicks the button.

Here's my UI code:

```
ui <- fluidPage (
  titlePanel("Religious Affiliations from 1900", windowTitle = "Browser"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.conditionedPanels == 1",
      sliderTextInput("years_map", "Select Year:", 
                      choices = years, selected = 2000,
                      animate = TRUE, grid = TRUE),
      selectInput("religion_1_map", "Religion 1",
                  choices = c("All", religion_names), 
                  selectize = TRUE),  
      selectInput("denom_1_map", "Denomination 1",
                  choices = c("All", "None", denomination_names), 
                  selectize = TRUE),
      selectInput("geography_1_map", "Geography 1", 
                  choices = c("World", all_geography, names(all_regions)), selectize = TRUE),
      selectInput("religion_2_map", "Religion 2",
                  choices = c("All", religion_names),
                  selectize = TRUE),
      selectInput("denom_2_map", "Denomination 2",
                  choices = c("All", "None", denomination_names),
                  selectize = TRUE),
      selectInput("geography_2_map", "Geography 2",
                  choices = c("World", all_geography), selectize = TRUE),
      actionButton("map_button", "Map my choices!")
    ),
  mainPanel(width = 9,
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Maps", 
      leafletOutput("mymap"),
               value = 1),

      tabPanel("Stacked Area Chart", 
               "test2",
               value = 2),
      tabPanel("Pie Chart", value = 3),
      tabPanel("Line Chart", value = 4),
      tabPanel("Statistics", value = 5),
      tabPanel("Data", value = 6),
      id = "conditionedPanels"
      )


server <- function(input, output) {


  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()
    #Make the map dependent on the button
    input$map_button
  })

  year <- reactive({
    all_cleaned %>% filter(year == input$years_map)
  })

  religion_1 <- reactiveValues({
    if(input$religion_1_map == "All") {
      year()
    }
    else if(input$religion_1_map == "None") {
      return()
    }
    else {
      year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_1_map)
    }
  })

  denom_1 <- reactive({
    if(input$denom_1_map == "All") {
      religion_1()
    }
    else if(input$denom_1_map == "None") {
      religion_1[!duplicated(religion_1[,'religion']), ]
    }
    else {
      religion_1() %>% filter(denom == input$denom_1_map)
    }
  })

  geography_1 <- reactive({
    if(input$geography_1_map == "All") {
      denom_1()
    }
    else if(input$geography_1_map == "None") {
      return()
    }
    else {
      denom_1() %>% filter(country_name %in% input$geography_1_map)
    }
  })

  religion_2 <- reactiveValues({
    if(input$religion_2_map == "All") {
      year()
    }
    else if(input$religion_2_map == "None") {
      return()
    }
    else {
      year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_2_map)
    }
  })

  denom_2 <- reactive({
    if(input$denom_2_map == "All") {
      religion_2()
    }
    else if(input$denom_2_map == "None") {
      religion_2[!duplicated(religion_2[,'religion']), ]
    }
    else {
      religion_2() %>% filter(denom == input$denom_2_map)
    }
  })

  geography_2 <- reactive({
    if(input$geography_2_map == "All") {
      denom_2()
    }
    else if(input$geography_2_map == "None") {
      return()
    }
    else {
      denom_2() %>% filter(country_name %in% input$geography_2_map)
    }
  })

  proxy <- observeEvent(input$map_button, {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(data = geography_1()) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = geography_2())
  })

}
```

**Update: To fix the problem of subsetting from a reactive filter, I simply cleaned my data instead for a workaround. It now works.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is hard to give you a proper answer without your `server.R` file. In my opinion this is pretty straight forward `reactive` and/or `eventReactive` Programming. The easiest way is to label the data (entrys and columns) the way you want it to be displayed in the UI. This enables reactive programming. Please upload your current `server.R` file or a reproducible example.

**EDIT:**
Call filtered dataset from the `reactive` the shiny way: `year` --> `year()` change the second reactive from:

```
religion_1 <- reactive({
if(input$religion_1_map == "All") {
  year
}
else if(input$religion_1_map == "None") {
  return()
}
else {
  year %>% filter(religion == input$religion_1_map)
}
})
```

to this:

```
religion_1 <- reactive({
if(input$religion_1_map == "All") {
  year()
}
else if(input$religion_1_map == "None") {
  return()
}
else {
  year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_1_map)
}
})
```

and respectively the others as well.

**Update**
    server <- function(input, output) {

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet() %>% addTiles()
#Make the map dependent on the button
input$map_button
})

year <- reactive({
all_cleaned %>% filter(year == input$years_map)
})

religion_1 <- reactiveValues({
if(input$religion_1_map == "All") {
  year()
}
else if(input$religion_1_map == "None") {
  return()
}
else {
  year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_1_map)
}
})

denom_1 <- reactive({
if(input$denom_1_map == "All") {
  religion_1()
}
else if(input$denom_1_map == "None") {
  unique(religion_1())
}
else {
  religion_1() %>% filter(denom == input$denom_1_map)
}
})

geography_1 <- reactive({
if(input$geography_1_map == "All") {
  denom_1()
}
else if(input$geography_1_map == "None") {
  return()
}
else {
  denom_1() %>% filter(country_name %in% input$geography_1_map)
}
})

religion_2 <- reactive({
if(input$religion_2_map == "All") {
  year()
}
else if(input$religion_2_map == "None") {
  return()
}
else {
  year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_2_map)
}
})

denom_2 <- reactive({
if(input$denom_2_map == "All") {
  religion_2()
}
else if(input$denom_2_map == "None") {
  unique(religion_2())
}
else {
  religion_2() %>% filter(denom == input$denom_2_map)
}
})

geography_2 <- reactive({
if(input$geography_2_map == "All") {
  denom_2()
}
else if(input$geography_2_map == "None") {
  return()
}
else {
  denom_2() %>% filter(country_name %in% input$geography_2_map)
}
})

proxy <- observeEvent(input$map_button, {
leafletProxy("mymap") %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(data = geography_1()) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = geography_2())
})

}
```

Comment: So I tried your code and I have several problems running it, because there are missing vectors (i.e. years)... But from looking at your `server.R` file I can see some one rather large mistake: you should structure every single filter in a its own `reactive` function. By this logic you do not have to define almost no `if` conditions.

Comment: Start with Denomination: 
`religion <- reactive({data <- filter(unfiltered dataframe, filter condition)})`
Now you can use religion as your "filtered" data frame in the next filter like this:
`denomination <- reactive({data <- filter(religion(), filter condition})`
try to place one filter condition in each reactive.

Comment: Call filtered dataset from the `reactive` the shiny way: `year` --> `year()` change the second reactive from: `religion_1 <- reactive({
    if(input$religion_1_map == "All") {
      year
    }
    else if(input$religion_1_map == "None") {
      return()
    }
    else {
      year %>% filter(religion == input$religion_1_map)
    }
  })`  
to 
`religion_1 <- reactive({
    if(input$religion_1_map == "All") {
      year()
    }
    else if(input$religion_1_map == "None") {
      return()
    }
    else {
      year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_1_map)
    }
  })`

Comment: Can you update your server code again? In my opinion shiny detects the changes so you could solve this issue with another reactive.

Comment: What do you want to acchieve with this line:
`religion_1()[!duplicated(religion_1()[,'religion']), ]`